# Visual Studio 2012 TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have created a project in VisualStudioOnline and then I added my solution to Source Control in TFS. Now I am using other computer and I want to continue my work. How can I load my project in VS2012? I am connected to TFS but I can't open my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git then you need to open Team Explorer in visual studio and select "Connect". Your VSO account should be listed, if not add it, and you can select your team project. Once connected you should see a list of Git repos. Select one and click "clone"

If you are using TFVC you will need to select "Source explorer" and map your workspace locally. You should, once connected, see the solutions listed at the bottom of the UI. Just double click to map a workspace and open...